# concatenation of 2 char arrays using strcat

Tags: c++

How to concatenate to char* in C++?
i tried using strcat but that only works for char* and a string. strcpy doesn't give the required output as i believe it overwrites the value in first array from the second.
i need to do something like this in C++ 
(this what i do in java)

```
seat=seat+tempGuest.toString()+". " //Java
```

`strcat_s(p, 150,seating[i][j].toString())`;

this gives an error as `seating[i][j].tostring()` returns a char* type.

this is my function code

```
char* Auditorium::toString(){


    char* p = new char[150];
    cout << "The current seating is\n";
    cout << "-------------------------\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < rowNum1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnNum1; j++)
        {

            strcat_s(p, 150,seating[i][j].toString());
            strcat_s(p, 150," ");


        }
        strcat_s(p, 150,"\n");

    }
    return p;

}
```

`seating[i][j].toString()` is getting value from the following function

```
char* Guest::toString()
{

    char * p = new char[30];

    p[0] = firstName[0];
    p[1] = '.';
    p[2]=lastName[0];
    p[3] = '.';
    p[4] = '\0';
        return p;
}
```

Comment: Can you not simply de-reference `seating[i][j]` ( and `p` ) ?

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and add the declarations of all variables. And why do you use raw `char` pointers? In C++ you should rather use `std::string`. Also read this: [mcve].

Comment: _this gives an error as seating[i][j].tostring() returns a char* type._ Which error? [edit] your question and paste the verbatim error message.

Comment: i need to return a char* value so making a new char* to store the returning values seemed appropriate

Comment: @khan if you want a good answer please [edit] your question and put all necessary information _there_ as requested in previous comments.

Comment: @MichaelWalz my whole code is too big for me to post here. i just wanna know that how can i return all the value in a single string. seating[i][j].toString() returns something like this  ?.?.
so i need to store it so that i can show it as 
?.?. ?.?. A.S.
?.?. S.K. ?.?
hope you got my point

Comment: @khan please post the error message you get. Statements such as _this gives an error_  are not really helpful

Comment: strcat_s(p, 150,seating[i][j].toString()); //Exception thrown (breakpoint triggered)

Comment: The way you use `strcat_s` looks correct. The problem is most likely within the dereferencement of `seating[i][j]`. Put `printf ("%s\n", seating[i][j].toString());` before `strcat_s(p, 150,seating[i][j].toString());`, then you'll probably get the problem there. Learn how to use the Visual Studio debugger.

Comment: i was doing it with cout<<seating[i][j].toString() and was getting the correct result so dereferencement is working fine.

Comment: So there must be some bug in the code you don't show. Learn how to use the debugger. I'm giving up here.

Comment: You are walking the wrong path. C++ automatically manages allocation and de-allocation when you use `std::string`, but you must consistently call `delete[]` on any array you allocate with `new[]` to avoid memory leaks. If you are a beginner do yourself a favour and stick to `std::string`, and if you want for learning purposes dig into raw allocation build a simplified [mcve] so that we can help you to fix the errors.

Comment: Additionally, current code does leak memory but does not exhibit any error. The error is in currently not shown code, and is probably related to memory management

Answer (score 3):

In C++, you use `std::string`. In this case you could even use a string stream:

```
#include <sstream>

std::string Auditorium::toString() {

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "The current seating is\n";
    oss << "-------------------------\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < rowNum1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnNum1; j++) {
            oss << seating[i][j].toString();
        }
        oss << "\n";
    }
    return oss.str();
}
```

Without the stream, consider:

```
std::string Auditorium::toString() {

    std::string result;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowNum1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnNum1; j++) {
            result += seating[i][j].toString();
            result += ' ';
        }
        result += '\n';
    }
    return result;
}
```

### BONUS

Even more in C++ style, don't provide a `toString`, but provide `operator<<`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3de4a034d913a50e)</kbd>**

```
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

struct Guest {
    std::string firstName, lastName;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Guest const& g) {
        return os << g.firstName[0] << '.' << g.lastName[0] << '.';
    }
};

namespace {
    using Row = std::array<Guest, 12>;

    inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Row const& row) {
        for (Guest const& guest : row)
            os << guest << " ";
        return os;
    }
}

struct Auditorium {
    std::array<Row, 10> seating;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Auditorium const& auditorium) {

        for (Row const& row : auditorium.seating)
            os << row << "\n";

        return os;
    }
};

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Auditorium auditorium {
        Row {Guest {"Jacob","Lettsom"}, {"Brion","Peasee"}, {"Kelvin","Tomasoni"}, {"Marabel","Fere"}, {"Hertha","Bartlam"}, {"Devondra","Grahl"}, {"Ike","Annott"}, {"Patrick","Cheyenne"}, {"Eada","Dawe"}, {"Marget","Glashby"}, {"Henderson","Glaum"}, {"Cassie","Winsom"}},
        Row {Guest {"Pierson","Kitchen"}, {"Elisha","Pass"}, {"Shirline","Wigin"}, {"Lucas","Stanmore"}, {"Norri","Hitzschke"}, {"Mercedes","Blackboro"}, {"Nappie","Breche"}, {"Freda","Mitton"}, {"Neils","Adamou"}, {"Mack","Rannells"}, {"Gaspard","Christoffersen"}, {"Sherwin","Kenwell"}},
        Row {Guest {"Wallas","Chellam"}, {"Doralin","Corthes"}, {"Sebastien","Scoble"}, {"Domini","Sprott"}, {"Lazaro","Bunton"}, {"Hinda","Korn"}, {"Renata","Vogt"}, {"Delmar","MacDwyer"}, {"Violette","Villiers"}, {"Nicko","McDirmid"}, {"Susanetta","MacCaughey"}, {"Hillary","McNuff"}},
        Row {Guest {"Alex","Downie"}, {"Caro","Westrey"}, {"Burr","Kalkofer"}, {"Ruy","Shelmerdine"}, {"Winfield","Beri"}, {"Isacco","Ellwell"}, {"Gideon","Beaford"}, {"Simon","Blaylock"}, {"Willy","Kloser"}, {"Guillemette","Boult"}, {"Mariya","Oehme"}, {"Emory","Angless"}},
        Row {Guest {"Jammie","Klimek"}, {"Monro","Passman"}, {"Page","Kornes"}, {"Giorgio","Couttes"}, {"Alexine","Glayzer"}, {"Jeni","Ferschke"}, {"Rock","Farrants"}, {"Katrinka","Schnieder"}, {"Irina","Ault"}, {"Antonetta","Griss"}, {"Pammy","Bertenshaw"}, {"Erinna","Terbeck"}},
        Row {Guest {"Evania","Sympson"}, {"Randy","Colvin"}, {"Legra","Osinin"}, {"Michaeline","Moroney"}, {"Adiana","Westbrook"}, {"Kellsie","Smeeton"}, {"Rodrick","Russ"}, {"Winny","Eggleston"}, {"Odille","Jerosch"}, {"Stacee","Liepina"}, {"Lucila","Jedras"}, {"Selma","Perch"}},
        Row {Guest {"Lynda","Palmar"}, {"Gracie","Jennick"}, {"Cleveland","Mordue"}, {"Elias","Manssuer"}, {"Kimbra","Cicchitello"}, {"Genni","Woliter"}, {"Gale","Baudassi"}, {"Johann","Swindlehurst"}, {"Andrei","De" "Laspee"}, {"Edythe","Dorr"}, {"Janela","Fydo"}, {"Silvia","Suerz"}},
        Row {Guest {"Rachel","Shoutt"}, {"Germain","Strangward"}, {"Margot","Son"}, {"Electra","Wookey"}, {"Samuel","Tight"}, {"Brande","Cable"}, {"Ford","Aitken"}, {"Noll","Woolf"}, {"Jourdan","Morewood"}, {"Milo","Trimming"}, {"Adair","Peck"}, {"Darnall","Loftus"}},
        Row {Guest {"Dene","Creer"}, {"Leena","Autry"}, {"Dickie","Wiggington"}, {"Josephine","Eagan"}, {"Hetty","Yoodall"}, {"Gayla","Dibson"}, {"Elwood","Torri"}, {"Eunice","Scapelhorn"}, {"Everett","Bedingfield"}, {"Ralf","Lodeke"}, {"Steve","Dockreay"}, {"Rod","Bruford"}},
        Row {Guest {"Siouxie","Rayment"}, {"Sheila-kathryn","Neal"}, {"Land","Beggi"}, {"Carson","Ferriman"}, {"Aile","Nias"}, {"Paige","Juckes"}, {"Cazzie","Leadstone"}, {"Selinda","Parlet"}, {"Rayner","Kesby"}, {"Murvyn","Laming"}, {"Lorianna","Pardey"}, {"Joane","Sneesby"}},
    };

    std::cout << auditorium << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
J.L. B.P. K.T. M.F. H.B. D.G. I.A. P.C. E.D. M.G. H.G. C.W. 
P.K. E.P. S.W. L.S. N.H. M.B. N.B. F.M. N.A. M.R. G.C. S.K. 
W.C. D.C. S.S. D.S. L.B. H.K. R.V. D.M. V.V. N.M. S.M. H.M. 
A.D. C.W. B.K. R.S. W.B. I.E. G.B. S.B. W.K. G.B. M.O. E.A. 
J.K. M.P. P.K. G.C. A.G. J.F. R.F. K.S. I.A. A.G. P.B. E.T. 
E.S. R.C. L.O. M.M. A.W. K.S. R.R. W.E. O.J. S.L. L.J. S.P. 
L.P. G.J. C.M. E.M. K.C. G.W. G.B. J.S. A.D. E.D. J.F. S.S. 
R.S. G.S. M.S. E.W. S.T. B.C. F.A. N.W. J.M. M.T. A.P. D.L. 
D.C. L.A. D.W. J.E. H.Y. G.D. E.T. E.S. E.B. R.L. S.D. R.B. 
S.R. S.N. L.B. C.F. A.N. P.J. C.L. S.P. R.K. M.L. L.P. J.S.
```

Comment: @sp2danny oops :)

Comment: why that `<iostream>` include appears right before `main()`?

Comment: @vasek it provides `std::cout`

Comment: @sehe sure but why it is not in the beginning of the file among the others?

Comment: @vasek no particular reason. I like this way because it shows people you can overload the operators without having `iostream`. See the rationale here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards#declare-near-first-use (related logic) I've fixed the headers a bit (wasn't using stringstream in the last example).

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::string` is a better option, as per [sehe's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe) answer.

However, I would like to add, if you ever feel tempted to type `new`
in C++, you are doing it wrong. Wrong as in gluing bird-feathers on a
rocket, or putting horseshoes on a car. C++ is built around the idea
of deterministic destruction, so if you want to 'grok' C++, first
order of business is switching over to value-semantics and [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii)